# TimeDistributed 2D CNN ValueError: strides should be of length 1, 1 or 3 but was 2

Tags: lstm, conv-neural-network

I work on TimeDistributed layers for my video data.
My input is of size (28620, 40, 140, 3) -> (28620 frames, hight=40, width=140, 3 RGB channels).

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(9, kernel_size=(3,3)), input_shape=(8, 40, 140, 3)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(1024, activation='relu', return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(250))
model.add(Dense(21))
```

When I fit with the following:

```
history = model.fit(input_train, gt_train, batch_size=8, epochs=50)
```

I get back the error:

```
ValueError: strides should be of length 1, 1 or 3 but was 2
```

I believe the error refers to the input_shape of the first layer, but I cannot figure out how deal with this error message.

I appreciate every hint or idea on how to fix this.